# BigQuery export to Avro format failing with "Internal Error"

Tags: google-bigquery

From BigQuery, I've tried running (since Apr 5) several export jobs (Avro format) to GCS, but I keep getting the error: "Internal Error".

What am I doing wrong?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3vgS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hitting the same error as in [this issue tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37010652); the internal error is due to the format of a particular column in your table. Please start or cc yourself on the bug to receive updates.